# How to use TypeAdapter for GSON with complicated JSONs in android

Tags: android, json, adapter, gson

I have a complicated JSON like below e.g.

```
{
 "nodes": [
   {
  "name": "some name",
  "links": {
    "link_name_1": [
      "name 1",
      "name 2"
    ],
    "link_name_2": [
      "name 1",
      "name 2"
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "property_name_xyz": {
      "property_name_xyz_1": "some value",
      "property_name_xyz_2": "some value"
    },
    "property_name_abc": {
      "property_name_abc_1": "some value",
      "property_name_abc_2": "some value",
      "property_name_abc_3": "some value"
    },
    "property_name_pqr": {
      "property_name_pqr_1": "some value",
      "property_name_pqr_2": "some value",
      "property_name_pqr_3": "some value",
      "property_name_pqr_4": "some value"
    }
   }
  },
  { 
   another similar object with different property names inside properties
  } 

 ]
}
```

I have already created a PoJos for all the above using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

I would like to know How can I use TypeAdapter to distinguish between different objects under. The difference can be made according to the properties of each Node object

```
 nodes
```

Comment: You have a Node pojo with an attribute Links that is also a Pojo an so on ?. I mean, does your Node pojo have all the json attributes ?

Comment: I can't understand what do you need, can you fill all the data into your pojos?